# Is it possible to have multiple environment files to be used in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, apache

So I am trying to have multiple laravel sites (different domains) use the same code base but with different environment files (.env) based on the domain. Is there a way I will be able to that. Example, I have domain1.com and domain2.com using the same code dir /var/www/laravel but domain1 will use .env1 file and domain2 will use .env2 file. This is all in the same server.

Any help will be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use multiple `.env` files. But you can create different config files for every domain and get the data with:

```
$domain = str_before(request->getHttpHost(), '.com'); // If domain is example.com, this will return 'example'
config($domain . '.some_value')
```

Comment: I think this solution cannot help with artisan. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use multiple environment files.

You can load different environment files in `bootstrap/app.php`

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "domain1.com") {
    $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.domain1');
} else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "domain2.com") {
    $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.domain2');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The laravel framework would only load one `.env`.

Here is what you should do:

1. Add multiple .env files to your project (e.g: `.env.domain1`, `.env.domain1` etc ..)
2. When you deploy to a domain copy the appropriate `.env` file (e.g: `cp .env.domain1 .env`

Comment: useful in plug and play !!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package that does this. It uses your servers hostname to determine which config it should load. It has a config file included that will allow you to setup a short common name for the server, and the actual hostname to determine the environment file to load.

When you run the artisan command that comes with the package, it will generate the `.env.environment` file you have setup in your `app/config/env_detector.php` file.

The package can be found here: https://packagist.org/packages/casperwilkes/laravel-environment_detector

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **bootstrap/app.php**
2. Find this part of code where **$app** is initialized:

```
    $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
        realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
    );
```

3. After that, past this code:

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && 
   !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && 
   $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'example.com' ){
    try {
        $envStaging = '.env.example.com';
        $app->loadEnvironmentFrom($envStaging);
        (new \Dotenv\Dotenv(
            $app->environmentPath(), 
            $app->environmentFile())
        )->load();
    } catch (\Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
        // No custom .env file found for this domain
        // Add any additional code if needed to handle this scenario
    }
}
```

4. Change **example.com** with your domain

You're good to go. This part of code will load only if the specific domain name is matched. This is great for staging domains, since code will not be executed on production domain at all.