# How to handle Multiple env file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Various confidential info like Mail, Payment Gateway info etc. We always kept in the **env** file according to a **Single Laravel Script** and **Single Database**. But in the case of Multi-Tenancy SAAS based applications, I mean **Single Laravel Script** but **Multiple Database** , how to create multiple **env** files for maintaining Multiple mail, payment gateway etc sensitive info.

Or have any alternative solutions ?

Though we can store it in the database and continue working but this is not a good solution to keep sensitive info in the database.

Comment: Check this answer or other answer in the same page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54321368

Comment: Though you would need to restart artisan serve or nginx/apache

Comment: Might be worth to think about containers like Docker.
There you can overwrite or set environment variables per instance.